# Is there any way to generate facebook login timestamp?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

On my site I have used fb login and I can do it easily for my site. But as we have users fb login id and other details, is it possible to generate facebook login time stamp for user for `www.facebook.com`.

Something like varifying how many times user performs facebook login and how many times he comes to my site.

or something nearer to this if possible

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand what you want to do, if you just want a timestamp for when you receive the response from Facebook then you can just create one on your side of the code using time(). If you want to know anything about the user's login habits beyond you're site then that isn't possible due to privacy reasons I imagine.

Comment: yes I wanted to see uesr's login habit beyond my site